# Insert two tables together at once in database PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database

I just wondering if there is a possibility to insert into the database two tables at once like,

```
$query = sprintf("INSERT INTO table ('tableid')values('somevaleu'),INSET INTO table1 ('table1id')values('somevalue')");
```

or I need to do it separately like,

```
$query1 = sprintf("INSERT INTO table ('tableid')values('somevaleu')");
$query2 = sprintf("INSET INTO table1 ('table1id')values('somevalue')");
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802437/how-to-execute-two-mysql-queries-as-one-in-php-mysql

Comment: Which MySQL extension are you using, the old `mysql_*` functions, mysqli, or PDO?  Mysqli and PDO support multiple statements in one query.

Comment: write querys separately is best procedure

Comment: If by `at once` you mean execute both queries at the same time in parallel then no it is not possible. And for readability, seperate looks clearer.

Comment: @thegrede okay then no, you will have to issue them one at a time.  You could insert multiple rows into the same table but not different tables in one query.

Comment: @drew010 Thank you, I think this is the answer for my question,

Comment: @thegrede ok, I added it as an answer w/ a bit more detail.

Comment: @thegrede Please don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799) (see the [red box](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)). Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli).

Comment: @thegrede If you can't decide which, [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you. If you care to learn, [here is good PDO tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers). Even though many beginner tutorials still use `mysql_*` functions, this doesn't mean they are acceptable. As a beginner you should learn the modern libraries that are both easier and more secure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the old [mysql](http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php) extension (`mysql_*` functions), then you cannot issue multiple queries in one statement.

From the manual<sup>[1](http://us.php.net/mysql_query)</sup>:

> mysql_query() sends a unique query (multiple queries are not
>   supported) to the currently active database on the server that's
>   associated with the specified link_identifier.

If you were using [mysqli](http://php.net/mysqli) or [pdo mysql](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) then you can do multiple inserts in one query.

It would also be possible to insert multiple rows into the *same* table in one query using extended inserts, but not two different tables.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you trying to do this?  If it's just laziness, please just take the extra thirty seconds and use two separate statements.  If, OTOH, you want to do this because you need to make both inserts at the same time to keep your database consistent (e.g. updating an "orders" table and a "billing" table at the same time), you want to look into **transactions**.

Basically, a transaction (started with **BEGIN**) is a bunch of queries that get bundled together and, when you're done, you can either **COMMIT** and make them stick or **ROLLBACK** to throw them away (such as if there's an error and you want to abort the process).  They're not *exactly* executed at the same time but, on a COMMIT, they will either all succeed or none of them will go through.

Comment: And note that in order to use transactions, one must use InnoDB and not the more commonly default engine MyISAM.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `begin` to enclose multiple SQL statements:

```
$query = "BEGIN ";
$query .= "INSERT INTO table ('tableid')values('somevalue') INSERT INTO table1 ('table1id')values('somevalue') ";
$query .= "COMMIT";
```

Then run `$query`.

Comment: This is even I'm using the older function `mysql_`?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how your database is being queried.  A lot of the 3rd-party database abstraction libraries I've used only allow one SQL statement per execution.  But MySQL *can* accept multiple queries separated by a semicolon, as you propose.