# PHP multiple MYSQL commands in one mysql_query() query

Tags: php, mysql, command

I want to issue multiple mysql commands with one mysql_query function.
This is my code:

```
$query .= "INSERT INTO `users` VALUES(1,'stack','overflow');";
$query .= "INSERT INTO `posts` VALUES('other','stack','overflow');";
mysql_query($query);
```

If I do that I get a warning that my syntax would be incorrect. 
If I echo the output, copy it and execute it in phpMyAdmin it works.

Where is the error there?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802437/how-to-execute-two-mysql-queries-as-one-in-php-mysql

Perhaps duplicate?

Comment: See also [the documentation for `mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php): "sends a unique query (multiple queries are not supported)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need this?? https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php

Comment: Although in my experience, one query at a time is usually far simpler :)

Comment: how is the performance with executing mysql_query() for each query? I have like 100s of queries to insert per pageload

Comment: don't know about performance, you'd have to ask someone else for that; I incorrectly assumed this was a lower-scale project

Comment: I went with mysqli solution, thanks

Answer (score 4):

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `users` VALUES (1,'stack','overflow'), ('other','stack','overflow');";
mysql_query($query);
```

PHP does not support sending more than one query at a time via `mysql_query`, but you can achieve your result in a single one by using the above.

Comment: That does not insert values into posts table.

Answer (score 2):

according to http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query  mysql_query() sends a unique query (multiple queries are not supported) to the currently active database on the server that's associated with the specified link_identifier.

but this guy said that you just have to pass flag 65536 as mysql_connect's 5 parameter 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php#91669