# Insert DATA into 2 tables using one Query using PHP and Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables that I am trying to insert data into using PHP

```
Table: WINE
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|  wine_id  |  wine_type  | country  |  indicator  |  color  |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

wine_id is auto incremented, then This is my other table

```
Table: stock
 --------------------------------------
 |  stock_id  |  wine_id  | quantity  |
 --------------------------------------
```

For the STOCK table I have stock ID as Auto incremented and wine_id is foreign-key so All i need to insert is quantity.

I have a syntax like this:

```
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO TABLE1(field1, field2, field3) VALUES('value1',value2,value3) INSERT INTO STOCK(field) VALUES ('value1')");
```

If there is another way to do so please suggest and I would like some examples please.

Comment: You may also create a trigger on the first table that inserts a row to the second table, that would also work for bulk insert or multiple inserts at once for the first table: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-triggers/mysql-after-insert-trigger/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to separate your two `INSERT` statements with a semicolon.

This(`mysql_*`) extension is deprecated as of `PHP 5.5.0`, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the `MySQLi` or `PDO_MySQL` extension should be used. Switching to `PreparedStatements` is even more better to ward off SQL Injection attacks !

Comment: That's what I was going to say

Comment: i do not think that mysql_* support multiple query. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11106719/php-multiple-mysql-commands-in-one-mysql-query-query

Comment: I can't change my code to mysql* as I have done plenty work into it what do you suggest me doing? @shankar Damodaran

Answer (score 2):

You can run multiple INSERTS once, however you cannot insert into two tables from one single `INSERT` Statement.
Also make sure to get the last inserted ID with `LAST_INSERT_ID()` for the foreign key and use a semicolon `;` between the two INSERTS

Answer (score 2):

From the looks of it, what you're trying to do is:

1. Insert data into the `wine` table
2. Get the ID from the `wine` table
3. Insert the ID into the `stock` table

[mysql_query](https://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) does not support multiple queries. So, my suggestion would be:

```
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `wine` (`wine_type`, `country`, `indicator`, `colour`) VALUES ('Merlot', 'Australia', 'Dry', 'Red')");
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `stock` (`wine_id`, `quantity`) VALUES ('".mysql_insert_id()."', '0');");
```

Modifying of course to take into account your own variables and value sanitation. As has been mentioned, the `mysql_` functions are being deprecated, and you're best to move to a PDO structure for your database in the near future.

Comment: where would we get mysql_insert_id()

Comment: @BlueLeaf It's a function in PHP. However, as I commented three years ago, the mysql_ functions are deprecated, and you are best to look at PDO alternatives.

Comment: how can we use bind_param in this case?

Answer (score 1):

you can do it by
[multiple statement details](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.multiple-statement.php)

like this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO TABLE1(field1, field2, field3) VALUES('value1',value2,value3); INSERT INTO STOCK(field) VALUES ('value1');";

multi_query($conn,$sql);
```

you need to use `mysqli_*` for this. I assume `$conn` is your `mysqli` connection

Comment: Wher did you get $conn from? @Awlad Liton

Comment: @user3311898, This answer won't work for you as you are using `mysql_*` functions.

Comment: @user3311898: you must have to use `mysqli_*` for this. see details in the given link and my updated answer