# Query that works in phpmyadmin is NOT working in php page?

Tags: php, mysql, alter-table

I have tested this query in phpmyadmin & it returns exactly what I'm looking for...it duplicates **row1** & updates the title to **DUPLICATE**.

```
$sql = "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE  tmp 
        SELECT  `unit_id`,
                    `title`,
                    `status_id`,
                    `category_id`,
                    `tags`,
                    `access_id`
        FROM        unit_genData 
        WHERE       `unit_id`='1';
        ALTER TABLE tmp 
        DROP COLUMN `unit_id`;
        UPDATE      tmp 
        SET         `title` = 'DUPLICATE';
        INSERT INTO unit_genData 
        SELECT      0,tmp.* 
        FROM        tmp;
        DROP TABLE  tmp;";
```

Then I go and add it to a php page, and...

`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'ALTER TABLE   tmp DROP COLUMN`unit_id`; UPDATE tmp ' at line 10`

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: post php code too..how do you execute the query?

Comment: did you try surrounding the table name tmp with single quotes?

Comment: Are you calling this as a `stored procedure` or not?

Comment: Unless you are using [`mysqli_multi_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php), your query fails, as your query has to be 1 query only, so it is failing on your first `;`

Comment: Why create a table and then alter it with next query? Why not just create it the way you want it?

Comment: @MikeBrant in this event, I'm duplicating a row. Wanted to duplicate the selected row's data & create a new entry row

Comment: Ok. Why not Insert into ... Select ... Syntax instead of all the temp table business? You should be able to do thus with a single query.

Comment: @MikeBrant tried it but it wasn't working with the INSERT with no unit_id. I saw this temp table concept & it worked. Easy choice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `mysqli_multi_query()` for executing multiple queries.

```
$sql = "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE  tmp 
    SELECT  `unit_id`,
                `title`,
                `status_id`,
                `category_id`,
                `tags`,
                `access_id`
    FROM        unit_genData 
    WHERE       `unit_id`='1';
    ALTER TABLE tmp 
    DROP COLUMN `unit_id`;
    UPDATE      tmp 
    SET         `title` = 'DUPLICATE';
    INSERT INTO unit_genData 
    SELECT      0,tmp.* 
    FROM        tmp;
    DROP TABLE  tmp;";

$mysqli->multi_query($sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, PHP disables multiple statements in a single query.

Either run the two statements separately, or you can use `mysql_multi_query`.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.multiple-statement.php

(Question doesn't specify which MySQL interface is used.)

Note that if your code is subject to SQL Injection vulnerabilities, then enabling multiple statements per query can throw open the door to a whole boatload of nefariousness... ala Little Bobby Tables  http://xkcd.com/327/.

Answer (score 0):

If you're for some reason using `mysql` functions pass `CLIENT_MULTI_STATEMENTS` as `mysql_connect`'s 5th parameter to allow multiple statements in your queries.

More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13982705/1014858).