# How to create multiple tables using one sql query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm going to prepare an installation script for my website which is automatically creates database and it's tables.
How can I send every queries in one?
Here is the PHP code:

```
$table_query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ".TP."_usertypes(
                utid INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,PRIMARY KEY (utid),
                utname VARCHAR(255)
                )
                DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8
                COLLATE utf8_general_ci;

                CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ".TP."_users(
                uid INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,PRIMARY KEY (uid),
                utid INT(11) NOT NULL,FOREIGN KEY (utid) REFERENCES ".TP."_usertypes(utid) ON DELETE RESTRICT,
                username VARCHAR(255), 
                password VARCHAR(255),
                avatar VARCHAR(255)
                )
                DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8
                COLLATE utf8_general_ci";
mysqli_query($connection,$table_query) or die(mysqli_error($connection));
```

Thank you.

Comment: Does it return any errors?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Executing multiple SQL queries in one statement with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13980803/executing-multiple-sql-queries-in-one-statement-with-php)

Comment: @jitendrapurohit Every topics I saw was about other sql commands not CREATE TABLE.

Comment: @P.Yntema `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cando_users( uid INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT' at line 9`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With mysqli you're able to use multiple statements for real using `mysqli_multi_query()`.

Read more on multiple statements in the [PHP Docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.multiple-statement.php).

Answer (score 0):

> How can I send every queries in one?

You can't.

You need to send each query in a separate php call.