# You have an error in your SQL syntax - PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysqli, syntax-error, mariadb

I have the following code:

```
$combined = array_combine($idArray, $sumsArray);
    //print_r($combined);

foreach ($combined as $key => $value) {

        $sqlToUpdate .= "UPDATE tbl_test SET ing_ml='".$value."' WHERE ing_id=".$key.";";

    if(isset($_POST['update'])){

        if ($conn->query($sqlToUpdate) === TRUE) {
            echo "Record updated successfully<br /><br />";
        } else {
            echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error . "<br /><br />";
        }
    }
}
echo $sqlToUpdate;
```

the output from `echo $sqlToUpdate;` is:

```
UPDATE tbl_test SET ing_ml='-5' WHERE ing_id='22';UPDATE tbl_test SET ing_ml='-1' WHERE ing_id='19';UPDATE tbl_test SET ing_ml='9' WHERE ing_id='13';UPDATE tbl_test SET ing_ml='0' WHERE ing_id='11';UPDATE tbl_test SET ing_ml='5' WHERE ing_id='4';
```

If I copy this output, and run it directly in phpMyAdmin, it executes perfectly, and all 5 rows are updated.

However, when I try to execute it from the PHP page (clicking the update button, hence the "if isset") I receive the following errors:

```
Record updated successfully

Error updating record: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE tbl_test SET ing_ml='-1' WHERE ing_id='19'' at line 1

Error updating record: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE tbl_test SET ing_ml='-1' WHERE ing_id='19';UPDATE tbl_test SET ing_ml='9'' at line 1

Error updating record: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE tbl_test SET ing_ml='-1' WHERE ing_id='19';UPDATE tbl_test SET ing_ml='9'' at line 1

Error updating record: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE tbl_test SET ing_ml='-1' WHERE ing_id='19';UPDATE tbl_test SET ing_ml='9'' at line 1
```

So, the first query within the foreach executes fine and updates the DB, but the remaining 4 queries fail.  I have tried everything and can not figure out why this is.  I have tried adding backticks, single quotes etc around $value on its own, and around both $value and $key but nothing seems to work.

Comment: try $sqlToUpdate = "your query"; i dont think simultaneous query will work

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13980803/executing-multiple-sql-queries-in-one-statement-with-php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Use prepared statements!

```
$combined = array_combine($idArray, $sumsArray);

$stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE tbl_test SET ing_ml=? WHERE ing_id=?");
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $value, $key);
foreach ($combined as $key => $value) {
    $stmt->execute();
}
echo "Record updated successfully<br /><br />";
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I'm sure this is what I need to do, however after implementing this, it still isn't doing what I would expect it to do.  Is there a way of outputting what is being ran by `$stmt->execute();` so I can see what SQL is being executed on the DB?

Comment: you can var_dump($key, $value);

Answer (score 1):

Your `$conn->query($sqlToUpdate)` is inside a `foreach` loop, and your `$sqlToUpdate` variable is incremented through `.=` in this loop.

Each time you loop, you are re-executing former queries.