# How to run multiple query on single save button?

Tags: php, mysqli

When I click on the save button only `all_university` table updates but the `all_colleges` table has not been updated. How can I update two tables on one save button?

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['save'])) {
    $chk = implode(",", $_POST['company_name']);  
    $sql = "update all_university set placement = '$chk' where university_name = '".$_POST['university_name']."'";
    $sql = "update all_colleges set placement = '$chk' where college_name = '".$_POST['college_name']."'";
    $value = mysqli_multi_query($link,$sql);
    if($value == true){
        $msg .="<h5 style='color:green'>Successfull</h5>";
    } else {
        $msg .="<h5 style='color:red'>Error!</h5>";
    }
  }
?>
```

Comment: What does this have to do with JS, jQuery or HTML5?

Comment: Also to achieve what you need to you just need to make the calls separately. You're just overwriting the `$sql` value at the moment

Comment: refer this stack answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13980803/executing-multiple-sql-queries-in-one-statement-with-php

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter how many queries you have. Just run them all one by one.
Besides, you should be using **prepared statements**.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['save'])) {
    $chk = implode(",", $_POST['company_name']);  

    $sql = "update all_university set placement = ? where university_name = ?";
    $stmt = $link->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $chk, $_POST['university_name']);
    $stmt->execute();

    $sql = "update all_colleges set placement = ? where college_name = ?";
    $stmt = $link->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $chk, $_POST['college_name']);
    $stmt->execute();

    $msg .="<h5 style='color:green'>Successfull</h5>";
}
```

**DO NOT** use mysqli_multi_query(). It will do you no good and won't work the way you think.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the multi-query function, you have to concatenate the two query strings:

```
$sql = "update all_university set placement = '$chk' where university_name = '".$_POST['university_name']."';";
$sql .= "update all_colleges set placement = '$chk' where college_name = '".$_POST['college_name']."'";
```

And then execute `mysqli_multi_query`.

Or, as Rory already mentioned, just query twice using the normal `mysqli_query` function.

But you should really look into *prepared statements* as you are vulnerable to **SQL injection**!

Answer (score -1):

*`Separate both query with semicolon (;)`*

```
$sql = "update all_university set placement = '$chk' where university_name = '".$_POST['university_name']."';";
$sql = "update all_colleges set placement = '$chk' where college_name = '".$_POST['college_name']."'";
```

*`Then, Append Both Query.`*

```
$sql = "update all_university set placement = '$chk' where university_name = '".$_POST['university_name']."'";
$sql .= "update all_colleges set placement = '$chk' where college_name = '".$_POST['college_name']."'";
```

Execute it.

```
$value = mysqli_multi_query($link,$sql);
```

> The [mysqli_multi_query()](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_multi_query.asp) function performs one or more queries against
>   the database. The queries are separated with a semicolon.

Comment: *Dear Down voters, Please provide the reason for down voting.*