# Combine INSERT INTO SELECT, with DELETE at the same time

Tags: php, mysql

I have a button

```
<button onClick=sAve('save','."$id."']."')>SAVE</button>
```

Once I click it, I want to use AJAX to pass the parameters to the PHP page to perform the following task to MYSQL:

```
switch... case "Save":

$sql1 = "INSERT INTO permanent_table (id, user, email) 
         SELECT id, user, email 
         FROM temp_table WHERE id='".$_GET['id']."'";
$sql2 = "DELETE FROM temp_table WHERE id='".$_GET['id']."'";
```

Whereby permanent_table having same structure as temp_table. I tried to run both queries just like that but it is not working, so I guess that is not the right way.

In my case, my question is:

1. What is the real pro way to use PHP/sql to perform this task?
2. Is there any way I can simplify/combine it to a single query?

Comment: first of all: where do you want the phone value to go? You want to insert 4 values into 3 columns. Second: you could write a procedure to do this in 1 query. (a transaction could also be in place, should either of the queries fail)

Comment: You can run multiple queries with [mysqli_multi_query](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.multi-query.php), but you should explain what is not working with you way, do you get an error or what is happening?

Comment: read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13980803/executing-multiple-sql-queries-in-one-statement-with-php/13982705#13982705

Comment: I think the most important thing to advise, above other elements, is perhaps the use of a prepared statement.

It looks like you're injecting a value into an SQL statement directly from the URL, with no sanitation.  Fixing this should be a higher priority, which I think is closer to the answer of a better way to perform this task (even if it skirts around the optimisation issue).

Answer (score 0):

I think this is you want

```
<button onClick="$.post('/php file name/', {'save','."$id."'}, function(data){});">SAVE</button><br/>
```

Then you could run some query's in the PHP file.

```
$sql = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `permanent_table` (`id`, `user`, `email`) VALUES(?, ?, ?)";
$sql->bind_param("sss", $_GET['id'], "", "");
$sql->execute();

$sql = $conn->prepare("DELETE FROM `temp_table` WHERE `id`=?");
$sql->bind_param("s", $_GET['id']);
$sql->execute();

$sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT `id`, `user`, `email` FROM `temp_table` WHERE `id`=?");
$sql->bind_param("s", $_GET['id']);
$sql->execute();
//select last so that you can grab the results
```

Run them on your way (PDO or MYSQL)
I know a lot about query's so feel free to ask something to me!

Comment: *I know a lot about query's so feel free to ask something to me!* - Then you'd be instructing them to use prepared statements instead of passing variables directly. It is preferred not to use inline events rather attach them to the element in question

Comment: yeah I know but I give his answer on how he does it.

Comment: Besides the point, you could improve your answer by giving them extra information regarding security, it won't do you any harm.

Comment: Please do not give examples using an old deprecated API like mysql

Comment: **The `mysql` PHP extension is dead** -- Stop using the [`mysql` PHP extension](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php). It is old, deprecated since PHP 5.5 and completely removed in PHP 7.0. Use [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO_mysql`](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) instead.

Comment: Your syntax is wrong in your update, prepared variables don't need to be wrapped in singlequotes or doublequotes.

Comment: oops forgot about that !

Comment: In the question there is no `$_GET['user']` or `$_GET['email']`. Only a `$_GET['id']`. So the insert query could be done the way it is in the question. (apart from the prepared statement). And a check if the insert was successful before throwing away the temp information, would be handy.

Comment: thats true, but I added those values to show him what you possible can fill in