# PHP MYSQL Update Query with @variable not working

Tags: php, mysql, variables

In php I'm trying to update a table column call `order` with incremental value step by 10 where project = to 1;

My table name is : task
My table contain colomn : id,project,name,order

In phpmyadmin I succed with this query.

```
SET @order := 0; UPDATE `task` SET `order` = @order := @order + 10 WHERE project = 1 ;
```

Now in PHP I'm doing this:

```
$query = 'SET @order := 0; UPDATE `task` SET `order` = @order := @order + 10 WHERE project = "'.$project.'";';
$result = mysql_query($query) OR die(mysql_error());
```

If I echo my $query I have this.

```
SET @order := 0; UPDATE `task` SET `order` = @order := @order + 10 WHERE project = "1"
```

And I get this error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE `task` SET `order` = @order := @order + 10 WHERE project = "1" at line 1
```

Any  idea what is my issue;

I know I should user PDO or any more modern SQL stuff but this is a patch on and old project ;)

Comment: You are missing a semicolon in the php generated SQL

Comment: You can't put multiple queries in a single call to `mysqli_query()` or `PDO::query()`. Do them as separate calls.

Comment: @really_operator Where is the missing semicolon? You don't have to put a semicolon at the end of the query.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Executing multiple SQL queries in one statement with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13980803/executing-multiple-sql-queries-in-one-statement-with-php)

Comment: How is this code even running? mysql_query has been removed from PHP since version 7.0 and was deprecated for almost 10 years before. Oldest supported version is now 7.2. You need to upgrade and stop using this outdated code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't put multiple queries in a single call to `mysql_query()`. Split it into two calls:

```
$query = 'SET @order := 0'; 
mysql_query($query) OR die(mysql_error());
$query = 'UPDATE `task` SET `order` = @order := @order + 10 WHERE project = "'.$project.'";';
mysql_query($query) OR die(mysql_error());
```

Variables like `@order` persist between calls, since they're associated with the connection, not the call.