# update two tables with one query in mysql PHPMyadmin?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have two tables, `user_info` and `Friend_info`. I want to do that when user update his record in user_info then it should also b update in friend_info where `friend_id=user_id`. I have tried this

```
UPDATE user_info (name, user_email, Gender, DOB, contact, address) WHERE user_id='$user_id',
                 friends_info(name, user_email, Gender, DOB, contact, address) WHERE friend_id='$user_id'
                  values('$name', '$user_email', '$Gender', '$DOB', '$contact', '$address');
```

But its not working . Any other solution please. It'll be appreciated.

*I know this question is too late to ask now a days  but its my problem because i am confused after doing so many search and no query is working in my case.*

Comment: Why you are trying to update these two table at single query ?Try instead two update query .

Comment: because when user update his record in user_info table then it should be updated in friends_info also by executing one php file from android studio @BikashP

Comment: Then it should be run by executing two query also.Just write two query line by line.

Comment: You have a comma at the end of the first statement. This needs to be a semicolon ; But this is also not a nice way to write code. You want to run it in 2 different queries so if one fails you know the reason. If you do a search on "mysql transactions" you can also group the queries so if one fails the other change is removed.

Comment: @bebo -so is your problem solved? if yes you may accept the answer by clicking on a tick icon left side of answer you liked.

Comment: i will do this but first i am trying to solve my problem .. that is not solved yet @ncm

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear. So are you testing something like you want query in phpmyadmin. if not then you might need to do in as a transaction. but if its a test or such try this:

```
UPDATE user_info (name, user_email, Gender, DOB, contact, address) 
values('$name', '$user_email', '$Gender', '$DOB', '$contact', '$address') 
WHERE user_id='$user_id';
UPDATE friends_info(name, user_email, Gender, DOB, contact, address) 
values('$name', '$user_email', '$Gender', '$DOB', '$contact', '$address') 
WHERE friend_id='$user_id';
```

So this is two query which then they are gonna execute together. But now in PHP

check these:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/802474/2226796

https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php

[PHP + MySQL transactions examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2708237/2226796)

Comment: no its not working here i tried like this        $sql_query = "UPDATE      user_info (name, user_email, Gender, DOB, contact, address) 
     values('$name', '$user_email', '$Gender', '$DOB', '$contact', '$address') 
     WHERE user_id='$user_id'";
     "UPDATE friends_info(name, user_email, Gender, DOB, contact, address) 
     values('$name', '$user_email', '$Gender', '$DOB', '$contact',  '$address') 
     WHERE friend_id='$user_id'";
     if(mysqli_query($con,$sql_query))
     {
     echo "<h3>success</h3>";
    }

Comment: can u please explain it more? for example if query is working then its reply with success otherwise not . thanks

Comment: @bebo I updated my answer. You need also to see why you want to execute two queries together. check third link for transaction.

Answer (score 0):

You can join the two tables in your statement using user_id as the joining key.

```
    UPDATE user_info ui 
    INNER JOIN friends_info fi 
    ON ui.user_id = fi.user_id
    SET ui.name = $name,
    SET ui.user_email = $email,
    SET ui.Gender = $Gender,
    SET ui.DOB = $DOB,
    SET ui.contact = $contact,
    SET ui.address = $address,

    -- set friends_info

    SET fi.name = $name,
    SET fi.user_email = $email,
    SET fi.Gender = $Gender,
    SET fi.DOB = $DOB,
    SET fi.contact = $contact,
    SET fi.address = $address
    WHERE ui.user_id = $user_id;
```

Comment: please explain more. like with an example and how it works

Comment: sir its not working here and i want to update where friend_is=$user_di