# Adding constant to values in Mysql and updating the values to the result

Tags: php, mysql

I have got MySQL table with three columns 'primary Key','debit_cash','user_id' So now i want to update the debit_cash values to the corresponding user_id by adding "15" to the value already present. The debit_cash is in VARCHAR so i tried converting to int and sum it , but still the values in MySQL is not changing .

Here is my code:

```
<?php 
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
    //Getting values 
    $user_id = $_POST['user_id'];


    //importing database connection script 
    require_once('dbConnect.php');

    //Creating sql query 
    $sql = "SELECT cos_details.debit_cash AS debitCash,
            (convert(int, debit_cash)+15) AS updatedDebitCash
            FROM cos_details
            UPDATE cos_details SET debit_cash = '$updatedDebitCash'
            WHERE user_id = $user_id";

    //Updating database table 
    if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
        echo 'Updated Successfully';
    }else{
        echo 'Could Not Update Try Again';
    }

    //closing connection 
    mysqli_close($con);
}
```

Any one please help me.

Comment: You're trying to execute a multi query here. Use `mysqli_error($con)` against your query and you'll see the syntax error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to execute two mysql queries as one in PHP/MYSQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802437/how-to-execute-two-mysql-queries-as-one-in-php-mysql)

Comment: Just a small point: Cash normally has a decimal component?? Are you sure `INT` is the right thing to cast it to??

Comment: @Fred-ii- Esspresso pour moi si vois plat

Comment: **A:** Make it easier on yourself and dump your entire table, alter the column to be a type that math can be done, rather than trying to convert a varchar to an integer and run only one query at a time. How much clearer can I be here? I even said to check for errors but haven't responded back. If you're going to continue on your present route, then edit your question with the db schema and example values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that you don't need the select but the update only

```
  UPDATE cos_details SET debit_cash = cast( (convert(int, debit_cash)+15) as VARCHAR(20))
  WHERE user_id = $user_id
```

could be that your user_id is a string too so you should surround the value with  quote

```
  UPDATE cos_details SET debit_cash = cast( (convert(int, debit_cash)+15) as VARCHAR(20))
  WHERE user_id = '$user_id'
```

Comment: It is not updating the value in table @scais

Comment: @WilliamWilli I feel I have to say that if you are storing a number on a database it would simplify everything if you used an appropriate DATA TYPE to hold it. VARCHAR is not appropriate

Comment: i use it because some time i have to add Boolean values. if your know the answer just post it

Comment: @WilliamWilli   . which is the user_id data type ?

Comment: @scaisEdge the debit_cash is not updating .

Comment: @WilliamWilli So booleans are `1` and `0` they also dont add onto a VARCHAR very easily

Comment: @WilliamWilli   my question is simple  which is the data type you are using  for user_id  .. because the fact  the value is not updating (and you don't have error) mean thar my answer is sintactically right but the where condtion don't match .. so  .. if you tell  what i', asking a can try to help otherwise  .. ...

Comment: anyway  .. i have update my answer with a suggestion ...and i invite you to a more proper behavior with the others user that are  trying to help you ..

Comment: user_id is also varchar only

Comment: @WilliamWilli Do you have any columns on your database that are not VARCHAR?

Comment: @RiggsFolly i use True or False.