# How to update single table when condition is multiple and different?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to update the table.I have two update query but I want to use it in a single update query.Column name and  Where condition are different in both queries.Would you help me in this?

```
   $sql="UPDATE points SET hero='$total_hero'+'$points' WHERE user_id='$hero_id'"; 
   $sql="UPDATE points SET zero='$total_zero'+'$points' WHERE user_id='$zero_id'";
```

Comment: It is possible, but nothing wrong with doing it in 2 queries

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432/multiple-updates-in-mysql

Comment: but it is working only single query and that is the second one. First query is not working. I am using in else { $sql="UPDATE points SET hero='$total_hero'+'$points' WHERE user_id='$hero_id'"; 
 $sql="UPDATE points SET zero='$total_zero'+'$points' WHERE user_id='$zero_id'";}

Comment: Mr.German, I checked that, That is different question and query is also different

Comment: In your example code you are simply overwriting your string so the first query will never actually execute.

Comment: because, your second took precedence over your first; use a mutli-query. Edit: @jeroen GMTA, I actually hesitated before hitting that submit button lol

Comment: @Fred-ii- That explains the 2-second difference ;-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to execute two mysql queries as one in PHP/MYSQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802437/how-to-execute-two-mysql-queries-as-one-in-php-mysql)

Comment: @jeroen sure does ^

Comment: Thanks for replying Mr.Jeroen and Fred, Can you help me with single update query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of the below query

```
$sql="UPDATE points 
      SET hero= CASE WHEN user_id='$hero_id' THEN '$total_hero'+'$points' ELSE hero END, 
      zero= CASE WHEN user_id='$zero_id' THEN '$total_zero'+'$points' ELSE zero END 
      WHERE user_id='$hero_id' OR user_id='$zero_id'";
```

Hope this would help you out.

Comment: Thanks for replying Mr.Viki888. It's working for me perfectly.upvote from my side