# MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mariadb, ezsql

I have a problem in ezSQL.

Code:

```
$dbo->query("INSERT INTO chart_logs (chart_id, uname, option_id) VALUES ('1', '1', '1'); INSERT INTO chart_logs (chart_id, uname, option_id) VALUES ('2', '2', '2'); ");
```

Error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO chart_logs (chart_id, uname, option_id) VALUES ('2', '2', '2')' at line 1

But,

This Sql Query works phpmyadmin SQL Command successfully. I dont understand this. Why sql code doesnt work in ezsql query?

Comment: you're attempting to run a multi query and not using the function for it.

Comment: However, it's missing quotes in there.

Comment: Split it into multiple calls to `$dbo->query()` for each query.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802437/how-to-execute-two-mysql-queries-as-one-in-php-mysql seems to be a possible duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

ezSQL does not support running multiple statements in a single query. Each statement must be executed in a separate query.

*Original answer:*

Run just *one* SQL statement.

MariaDB supports multirow insert with VALUES clause...

```
  INSERT INTO chart_logs (chart_id, uname, option_id) VALUES
    ('1', '1', '1')
  , ('2', '2', '2')
```

Comment: Thanks it works, but same error DELETE query line 1?

INSERT INTO chart_logs (chart_id, uname, option_id) VALUES ('1', '1', '1'); DELETE FROM chart_logs where chart_id = 3;

Comment: As I said in the answer... run just *one* SQL statement in a query. That means the sql text should have *one* INSERT statement, or *one* DELETE statement. ( *ezSQL* does not support running multiple statements in a single query.)