# MYSQL) CREATE UNIQUE INDEX works in phpmyadmin but not in php script

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a really simple SQL script

```
$addQuery = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS WORDLIST(
        english VARCHAR(20),
        korean VARCHAR(20),
        swedish VARCHAR(20),
        synonyms TEXT
    );CREATE UNIQUE INDEX englishIndex ON WORDLIST(english);";
```

This query works in phpmyadmin

[image]

but when I do the same thing just in php script

[image]

database is empty.

BUT!
If I remove CREATE UNIQUE query in php and do just CREATE TABLE like this,

```
    $addQuery = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS WORDLIST(
        english VARCHAR(20),
        korean VARCHAR(20),
        swedish VARCHAR(20),
        synonyms TEXT
    );
    ";
```

[image]

php works, I just can't understand why. What's wrong with my code?

here is my full php code

```
<?php 
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000/');
$addValue = $_GET['Add'];
if (!preg_match('/[^A-Za-z]+/', $addValue)&&!preg_match('/\s/', $addValue))
 {
include 'db/db_connection.php';
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','worddb');
if(connectDB($conn)){
    $addQuery = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS WORDLIST(
        english VARCHAR(20),
        korean VARCHAR(20),
        swedish VARCHAR(20),
        synonyms TEXT
    );CREATE UNIQUE INDEX englishIndex ON WORDLIST(english);
    ";
    if (mysqli_query($conn, $addQuery)) {
        echo "Table WORDLIST created successfully";
      }
      echo $addQuery;
      mysqli_close($conn);
  }
 }else{
 echo "search again";
 }
?>
```

connectDB function is from db_connection.php

```
<?php 
function connectDB($conn){
    $connectStatus = null;
    if (!$conn) {
        $connectStatus = false;
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }else{
        echo "Connected successfully";
        $connectStatus = true;
    }
    return $connectStatus;
}
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried to run 2 separate queries? One `CREATE TABLE` and one `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX...` query

Comment: @B001ᛦ, Wait what the heck? I did exactly as you said, $addQuery = CREATE TABLE .... mysqli_query for $addQuery then $addQuery2=CREATE INDEX bla blah  mysqli_query for $addQuery2 ... and worked... I don't know any technical difference....

Comment: Adding a unique key during create table is simply `, UNIQUE KEY englishIndex (english)` after the other fields.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to execute two mysql queries as one in PHP/MYSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802437/how-to-execute-two-mysql-queries-as-one-in-php-mysql) (See the last part of the accepted answer)

Answer (score -1):

You can't combine multiple statements in a single `mysqli` query.  `phpmyadmin` is doing the work of parsing them out into separate queries for you.  Issue your two statements separately, or embed the index creation in the `CREATE TABLE`.